# What does the jquery $('<script>') do?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen this as

```
var script = $("<script />", {
  src: "http://some-url",
  type: "application/json"
  }
);
```

which is a snippet used in a tutorial about JSONP, used to add a script reference to the head element (which I completely understand), however I have not seen a JQuery expression like this before.

I usually see 
`$('some_css selector').some_method()...`
but the above syntax is unfamiliar to me.

I can see that it is building a script tab with the `src` and `type` properties set, but I am not familiar with the pattern used here.

So what exactly is it doing and can this pattern be used to do other things?

Comment: It creates a `<script>` dom object with the properties specified

Comment: See https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/#creating-new-elements

Comment: @wiomoc the downvote on your answer was due to the "it inserts ... into the DOM".  It does not insert into the dom.  It is a dom fragment until it is appended, which is not happening.

Comment: *can this pattern be used to do other things*...erm..yes

Comment: I'm sure this is a dupe but I can't find a good target

Comment: @Felix Kling - Thanks for the links, that clears it up. google search was notoriously unhelpful in finding the answer.

Comment: Right in the documentation for `$()` that explains everything that can be set in it https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes

Answer (score 1):

It's making a new element and storing it into a variable. For example, when you click the button here it will make a new div element and append it to the page

```js
$("#click").click(() => {
  var div = $("<div>", {
      class: "box",
    }
  );
  $("#container").append(div);
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button" id="click"></button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is just setting the HTML attributes at the time of declaration.

So that will create `<script src="http://some-url" type="application/json"></script>`

It creates a 'virtual' element (that doesn't exist in the DOM until you tell it to).

For example if you say

```
var x = $('<script>');
x = x.attr('src', 'http://some-url/file.js'
```

That virtual script tag is stored in `x`. You can choose what to do with it now:

```
$('body').append(x);
```

That will add the script tag to the `<body>`;